# Sort files into different folders based on their beginning

Tags: bash, sorting, for-loop, if-statement

I'm creating a script in BASH that will sort my files into different folders based on the beginning of the name. For example, the files are called A1_a.txt, A1_aa.txt, A1_aaa.txt, A2_aa.txt, A2_aa.txt, A2_aaa.txt. and based on whether they are A1 or A2 wants to move them to new1 for A1, and new2 for A2. I have to use a for loop for this task

I created such a script but it gets an error.

```
for i in $(ls | grep "A1"|"A2"); do if [ ${i} = "A1" ] then mv ${i} new1 else mv ${i} new2 fi; done
```

error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

I don't understand why he got such an error, badly created if in for loop?

After adding semicolons;
[image]

After adding semicolons and removing "" in grep, also switching all ${i} --> "$i" no error pops out, but also nothing happens
[image]

Comment: Why don't you just `mv A1* new1` and `mv A2* new2`?

Comment: @Renaud Pacalet I should use one command. But thanks for saying this :)

Comment: @NewbieProgrammer: addressing the syntax error: `for ... in ...; do if ... ; then ... ; else ... ; fi; done`

Comment: @Fravadona Yes, thank you for showing it so clearly. I typed:
for i in $(ls | grep "A1"|"A2" ); do if [ ${i} = "A1" ]; then mv ${i} new1; else mv ${i} new2; fi; done
and still got information "A2: command not found

Comment: @RenaudPacalet `{ mv A1* new1;  mv A2* new2; }` is one command 

Comment: @NewbieProgrammer as you don't double quote your variable expansions then I suppose that the filenames get in the way. you should replace all the `${i}` with `"$i"`

Comment: @NewbieProgrammer Please edit your question and add that this is an assignment and that one constraint is that you must use only one command. But what you wrote is not "_one command_", it's many: `for`, `ls`, `grep`, and a bunch of `if` and `mv` commands. If what you mean by "_one command_" is in fact "_one line_" just `mv A1* new1; mv A2* new2`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Smart! But technically this is one group command with two commands in it, and that's 3 ;-).

Comment: @NewbieProgrammer is it important to name the directories new1 and new2 ? you can have A1 and A2 as the directories and then you can just ```mv $i ${i:0:2}```

Comment: Summary:
Solution by @Fravadona f1=(A1*) f2=(A2*); for i in 1 2; do fi=f$i[@]; mv "${!fi}" "new$i/"; done    Works perfectly.
Back to my script. After adding semicolons and removing "" in grep, also switching all ${i} --> "$i" no error pops out, but also nothing happens... for i in $(ls | grep "A1|A2" ); do if [ "$i" = "A1" ]; then mv "$i" new1; else mv "$i" new2; fi; done

Comment: @NewbieProgrammer ```"A1|A2"``` is an extended regex so you need to pass the -E flag to grep. Also you are trying to match exactly with ```"A1"``` in filenames but you say your filenames are A1_aa,txt and so on. So you need to regex match the pattern like ```[[ $i =~ A1 ]]``` or [[ $i =~ A2 ]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to only write the `mv` command once then a sensible solution would be:

```bash
for i in 1 2
do
    mv "A$i"* "new$i/"
done
```